# What is the proper regular expression to cover multiple subdirectories?

Tags: regex

I'm configuring a job on jenkins to exlude files on a github pushes.  I want to exclude all pom.xml files, wherever the pom.xml would be located at (i.e. in the parent directory or any of the sub-directories.

**Currently, this works:**

```
(P|p)roject/[^/]+/pom.xml
(P|p)roject/[^/]+/[^/]+/pom.xml
(P|p)roject/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/pom.xml
(P|p)roject/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/pom.xml
```

**this also works, however this one-liner is messy:**

```
(P|p)roject/([^/]+|[^/]+/[^/]+|[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+|[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)/pom.xml
```

My question:  *Is there a cleaner one-liner regex that would cover the parent directory and its sub-directories?*

Comment: Is this for a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: can´t you just use `(P|p)roject/.+/pom\.xml` ?

Answer (score 2):

does following work?

```
(P|p)roject\/([^/]+\/)+pom\.xml
```

also note that you had not escaped forward slash and a dot character (.) which you should have

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
 # (?i)project/(?:[^/]*/)*pom\.xml

 (?i)
 project/
 (?: [^/]* / )*
 pom \. xml
```